# How i can download youtube videos by using cmd

Tags: command-line, video, cmd.exe, youtube, youtube-dl

in the first time of learning **command line** i've saw the quick performance that it presents and its deal with files, directories, and programs efficiently.
after all of that i think **command line** not only surrounded by this feature and i think has to much extra features and i wish from this features to be one for downloading videos from **youtube**.

anyway i have tried numerous of website and programs that can do that but often is not with required qualifications.

finally, i want something can do it by **cmd** prompt anything other i don't. **thanks all of you**

Comment: We do already have a lot of questions dealing with YouTube https://superuser.com/search?q=download+videos+youtube

Answer (score 0):

You need download youtube-dl from [youtube-dl.org](https://youtube-dl.org/). Once downloaded, find the place where it was saved to. For instance it might be in `c:\users\hp\downloads`

Next,

1. Open run dialog(Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) and type `cmd` in.
2. In `cmd` prompt open select the directory that youtube-dl program was saved to. For example(`c:\users\hp\downloads`)
3. after selecting go to YouTube video that you want and catch its URL.
4. Go to `cmd` prompt again and type

   ```
   c:\users\hp\downloads>youtube-dl "URL"
   ```
5. if did all this steps hit enter and wait a second to see the downloading run.
6. Note : all videos that is gonna download will install or place in the same directory where youtube-dl is saved.

These steps are for Windows but for others it should be similar